# how to return all the list item and show the all the list item on the screen/

Tags: javascript

I don't know how to return all the list item. I iterate the list and return the list items, it only shows the last item of the list on the screen and other list items does not show up. Here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      function test(t){ 
        var list = [];
        var integrr = parseInt(t);
        if (integrr < 4){
          integrr = integrr / 4;
          list.push(integrr);
          test(t);
        }
        else {
          list.push(integrr);
          for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            return list[i];
          }
        }
      }
      var te = test("20");
      document.write(te)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just `return list;` and get rid of that loop?

Comment: It's working as expected. 20 > 4, so it pushes 20 to list[], then returns that one item

Comment: I don't think that recursion ends if you call test for anything less than 4, so you have to change your logic too

Comment: Carcigenicate, Yes your right.

Comment: Yes, you are right Ramesh. I am trying to stop recursion in the else statement. Is there a possibility to stop recursion?

Comment: yes of course what are you writing your logic for? I mean how should list populate upon calling the function

Comment: I am trying to divide user input by 4 until user input gets less than 4

Comment: please share sample inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your response to comments for this question, I believe you are trying to take a number, and if that number is greater than 4, divide it by 4, add it to a list, and then try again. If that is true, I believe a while loop is better suited for this than an if/else.

```html
<html>
    <body>
       <script>
          function test(t){ 
               var list = [];
               var integrr = parseInt(t);
               while(integrr > 4){
                 integrr = integrr/4;
                 list.push(integrr);
               }
               return list;
          }
          var te = test("20");
          document.write(te)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```